# On what date does Ubuntu Server 10.04 reach end of life (EOL)?

Tags: server, 10.04, support

I was planning some migration and started to look around for exactly when Ubuntu Server 10.04 goes EOL. But all I can find is the month. Is there any official or unofficial date set to when Ubuntu Server 10.04 reaches end of life?

To be as explicit as possible with my question: Which specific **day** does Ubuntu Server 10.04 reach EOL. I know the month, but which day is it?

Comment: It is not a duplicate. The question you reference asks if it's possible to install 10.04 after it's EOL. This question asks for the specific **day** 10.04 reaches EOL.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have now found the date on the [Ubuntu Releases Site](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases). It is **April the 30th 2015**.

Answer (score 2):

The server version of Ubuntu 10.04 LTS (Update .4 from 16.Feb 2012) will reach end-of-life in April 2015.

As the first 10.04 LTS version ("Update .0") was released on 29.April 2010, I would assume that end-of-life will also be reached after exact 5 years, so on April 29.

For more details and a full list of all available versions and their release/EOL-dates, see https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases

Answer (score 1):

The [Ubuntu Release](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases) page only gives the exact date for EOL after the date has passed.

10.04 Server is currently listed as reaching EOL in April 2015. No specific date is given and there is no point in guessing; there's a 1 in 30 chance of getting it right (slightly higher if you assume they won't do it at weekend).

If I had a server that I didn't want to be running an unsupported OS, I'd assume that it will be 1st April 2015, and plan the migration accordingly.